# GridViewのデータバインディングが反映されない

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

ご教授よろしくお願いします｡

WPFのDataGridにObservableCollectionのインスタンスをバインドしております｡
DataGrdiの値を変更したら､他の列の情報を自動で更新したいのですが､画面に反映されません｡｡(実際のインスタンスの値は変わっている)
自動で画面更新されない理由と､更新する方法をご教授ください｡

xamlファイルは以下の通りです｡

```html
<DataGrid Name="gridTest" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value1"  Binding="{Binding Value1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value2" Binding="{Binding Value2}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value3" Binding="{Binding Value3}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

コードビハインドは以下の通りです｡

```html
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ObservableCollection<Item> ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            ItemList.Add(new Item() { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 4 });
            ItemList.Add(new Item() { Value1 = 2, Value2 = 4 });
            ItemList.Add(new Item() { Value1 = 3, Value2 = 6 });

            this.gridTest.DataContext = ItemList;
        }
        
        public class Item
    {
        int _value1;
        int _value2;
        int _value3;

        public int Value1
        {
            get
            {
                return _value1;
            }
            set
            {
                _value1 = value;
            }
        }
        public int Value2
        {
            get
            {
                return _value2;
            }
            set
            {
                _value2 = value;
            }
        }
        public int Value3
        {
            get
            {
                _value3 = _value1 + _value2;
                return _value3;
            }
            set
            {
                _value3 = value;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

ItemクラスのValue3はValue1+Value2を常に取得する想定です｡
この時､画面上でGridViewのValue1を値変更してもValue3の値が更新されません｡
ただし､バインディングされているインスタンスのValue3はValue1 + Value2になっています｡

試しにValue3のセルをダブルクリックして編集モードになると､Value1+Value2の値になります｡
以下はその様子のサンプル画像です｡
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
1行目ののValue1を1から10に変更した時にValue3が変わっていません｡
ただし､Value3のセルをダブルクリックすると
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
のように変わります｡｡｡

どなたか解決方法を教えてください｡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Item`に`INotifyPropertyChanged`を実装してイベントを発生させてください。

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _value1;
    int _value2;
    int _value3;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return _value1;
        }
        set
        {
            _value1 = value;

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value1)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value3)));
        }
    }
    public int Value2
    {
        get
        {
            return _value2;
        }
        set
        {
            _value2 = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value2)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value3)));
        }
    }
    public int Value3
    {
        get
        {
            _value3 = _value1 + _value2;
            return _value3;
        }
        set
        {
            _value3 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

なお`_value3`フィールドと`Value3`のセッターはプロパティの値を変更しないので無意味です。

Comment: ありがとうございます｡　求めている結果になりました｡